# Scoping issue with terser-webpack-plugin options

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, terser

I have a situation where I don't have Terser configured correctly and it's causing the compressed version of my page to break. My issue is that I have some functional declarations in my index.js. These declarations need to be accessible from Bootstrap modal windows that can be loaded in at a later time.

For example, in my `index.js` there is a function declared like this:

```
function doThis() { }
```

Then, say, a user opens an address form in a modal window, and a different javascript file called 'address-form.js' is loaded. In this form there is a button with an onclick handler that calls `doThis()`. The onclick handler lives in 'address-form.js' but is able to access `doThis()` in the parent index.js. The button works fine when index.js isn't compressed. But after it's compressed, I get an error saying `doThis()` doesn't exist.

I believe this to be a scoping issue, because I do see the `doThis()` declaration in `index.js`, but it appears to be wrapped in a bunch of parentheses. I'm not sure how to make the scope of doThis() the top-level window. The same scoping issue exists for literally hundreds of function declarations and variables in `index.js`, so I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to tinker too much with the gargantuan file.

Notice if I change the function declaration to an expression, it DOES seem to work:

```
window.doThis = function() {
}
```

However, because there are hundreds of `vars` and `const` and `let` variables in the file (in addition to dozens of function declarations), it's not really practical for me to change the scope of all of them just so the compression will work.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync('./js/Pages/*.js').reduce((object, element) => {
    object[path.parse(element).name] = element
    return object
  }, {}),
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/Pages/minified')
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
          compress: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
          keep_classnames: true,
          ie8: false,
          safari10: false,
          toplevel: false
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ]
}
```

The command I'm running is:

`webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.js`

## SOLUTION

Solution as accepted below was to use terser-cli directly. I wrote a little script that runs terser on every file in a directory if anyone should find it helpful:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const Terser = require('terser')
const srcDir = '../js/Pages'
const destDir = '../js/Pages/minified'


function minifyPagesDir() {
  let srcFileNames = fs.readdirSync(srcDir).filter(path => path.match(/\.js$/)) || []
  let srcFilePaths = []
  
  let destFilePaths = srcFileNames.map((item, i) => {
    srcFilePaths[i] = `${srcDir}/${srcFileNames[i]}`
    return `${destDir}/${item}`
  })

  if (!fs.existsSync(destDir))
    fs.mkdirSync(destDir)
  
  srcFileNames.forEach((item, i) => {
    exec(
      `terser ${srcFilePaths[i]} -c -o ${destFilePaths[i]} --ecma 2021`,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error !== null)
            console.log(`RUHROH: ${error}`, ' stderr: ', stderr);
      }
    )

    console.log(`Minified '${srcFilePaths[i]}' to '${destFilePaths[i]}'!`)
  })
  console.log('Minification complete!')
}

minifyPagesDir()
```

Comment: Is the only change you made enabling terser? Or is webpack also new? It's normally webpacks job to resolve dependencies between files, but it seems like you're trying to sidestep it here and do that manually. Thats generally going to cause you problems. If you haven't used webpack before, you could run terser without webpack.

Comment: I did run Terser from the command line and got the same errors. There's nothing really to sidestep...  the javascript files are just jquery event handlers in old-school .js files. They're not modules that interlink, so there's no opportunity for webpack to analyze the codebase as a whole

Comment: I'm hoping there is a magical Terser option that will prevent the global variables from being scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a repro project with your configuration and verified that your problems are not caused by terser, but by webpack.

I've used the following test file:

```js
function doThis() { }
```

With `minimize` *disabled* and no `minimizer` set, this is the result of building the test file with webpack:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
function doThis() { }
/******/ })()
;
```

If we reformat it and remove the comments, it's clear that everything inside the file is **dead code**. Webpack is a bundler and wraps everything in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This means that functions won't be assigned to global scope.

```js
(() => {
  var __webpack_exports__ = {};
  function doThis() { }
})();
```

Since you're not exporting anything or causing any side-effects, like assigning to `window`, terser will remove the content. This is correct and even without removing it, you still would get the same errors, since the function in webpack's output is not assigned to the global scope and your handlers couldn't access it. Compressing webpack's export with the terser cli results in an empty file.

Running the terser cli directly on the test input file, results in the desired compressed output:

```js
function doThis(){}
```

You said you've ran terser from the command line and had the same problems as when bundling and compressing through webpack. Did you run the source files through terser or the output of webpack? Because running the source files through terser should result in the desired output. Please try running `terser foo/bar.js -c -o foo/bar.min.js` and test if it solves your problem.

If you want to use webpack, you need to either assign to `window` or  move away from using global scope altogether.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this was very helpful. Instead of using webpack, I wrote a little nodejs script that runs `terser` directly on every file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when it was added, but webpack has an `IIFE` option.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputiife

But unfortunately, it always generates unnecessary code `var __webpack_exports__ = {}`.

I don't know how to delete that code.
I would like to know if there is an option.